# How do I make my AppleScript detect when I move its application?

Tags: applescript

So, I am trying to create an app with AppleScript, but when I move my app in a different folder and run it, it always will look at the folder it was in before.

```
display dialog "Kindle Fire HDX 7" Utility Mac
Please select the action you want to do.
Make sure a Terminal window is OPENED!!!" 
buttons {"Connected Devices", "Reboot", "More..."} default button 3
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Connected Devices" then
-- action for 1st button goes here
tell application "Terminal"
```

VVVV Right here is error

```
    if (count of windows) is not 0 then
        do script "cd ~/Desktop/ADB-GUI/Kindle Fire HDX 7" Utility.app/Contents/Resources/minerboyadb/ && ./adb devices"
```

^^^^ Right here is error

```
    end if
else if the button_pressed is "" then
-- action for 2nd button goes here
else
-- action for 3rd button goes here
end if
```

Is there a way to fix this? Or is it possible to use Xcode to make an AppleScript app? (Which might work better.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as posted as of this writing, won't compile, but to answer the question in general:

```
POSIX path of (path to me)
```

will return the POSIX path to the running AppleScript-based application from within it, including a trailing `/`; e.g.: `"/Applications/MyAppleScriptApp.app/"`

---

Aside from that, you should always use `quoted form of` when adding an argument to a shell-command string for use with `do script` or `do shell script`, so as to ensure that it is preserved as-is and doesn't break the overall shell command.

---

Furthermore, assuming your intent is to simply display/capture the output from a shell command, use `do shell script`, which runs a shell command *hidden* and returns its stdout output; e.g.:

```
set cmdOutput to do shell script "ls"
display alert "Files in current folder" message cmdOutput
```